# Birt Arabic displayed as blank

Tags: fonts, birt, arabic

I am using birt 4.2, And when using font "Time new Roman" it is displayed fine in birt viewer but when deploy the report into WAS the arabic words displayed blank.

What is the issue ?

Comment: I am facing same issue.
If you have find any solution then please post it.

Comment: @NIket, The issue fixed by installing a new font in the server that support special characters. The one i used named "DejaVu Sans". So just install the font in the server, restart, and give it a try.